# Implementing authlogic for rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin and I liked it very much. The only problem is that it is coupled with devise for authentication, but my whole app is implementing authlogic.
      Ain't there any way to remove devise so that I can switch to my existing authlogic authentication. I googled it but couldn't find :( 
Regards;
Kshitiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about removing devise, it seems to be a requirement for installing rails_admin. So you need to install it even if you don't use it.

But you can make rails_admin use authlogic for authentication and authorization like so.

- In your config/initializers folder, create a new file calls rails_admin.rb
- Put the following inside the file (note that I used nifty_generators so I have some helper methods available to me like `logged_in?` etc. You might need to use the equivalent methods in your setup):
- Now restart your server!

Code:

```
RailsAdmin.authenticate_with{
  unless logged_in?
    session[:return_to] = request.url
    redirect_to login_url, :alert => "You must first log in or sign up before accessing this page."
  end
}

RailsAdmin.authorize_with{
  redirect_to root_path, :alert => "You are not authorized to access that page" unless current_user.admin? #or whatever you use for checking admins
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently got familiar with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), and man, it's a great permissions interface to have around. I'd been wanting to install cancan at some point, and although it's extremely undocumented, I stumbled on [this pull request to rails_admin by Ryan Bates](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/301) in my search for the same answer. I used this as an excuse to install both CanCan and RailsAdmin, and can confirm that so far at least they fit extremely well together.

The commit instructions are a bit dated, so here's what worked for me.

in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
```

in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan
end
```

In your abilities:

```
can :access, :rails_admin
can :history
```

you probably already know this, but for prudence, in `config/routes.rb`

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

Finally, if you `bundle install` in the following way, it won't pull in devise! Hackish, but better than the alternative.

```
AUTHORIZATION_ADAPTER=cancan bundle install
```

Anyways, you might not want CanCan, but if you do, you'll probably be stoked to have this work in a supported (although undocumented) way.